# Execution failed for task ':assets_audio_player:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm experiencing this error whenever I try to run the code after trying to add "assestsAudioplayer" to my code

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':assets_audio_player:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14m 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'll display the lines of code added that brought about the error and what dart file they were on

```
final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();
```

my configMaps.dart file

```
void retrieveRideRequestInfo(String rideRequestId, BuildContext context)
  {
    newRequestsRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot)
    {
      if(dataSnapShot.value != null)
      {
        assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio("sounds/alert.mp3"));
        assetsAudioPlayer.play();

        double pickUpLocationLat = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());
        double pickUpLocationLng = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['pickup']['longitude'].toString());
        String pickUpAddress = (dataSnapShot.value['pickup_address'].toString());

        double dropOffLocationLat = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['dropOff']['latitude'].toString());
        double dropOffLocationLng = double.parse(dataSnapShot.value['dropOff']['longitude'].toString());
        String dropOffAddress = (dataSnapShot.value['dropOff_address'].toString());

        String paymentMethod = dataSnapShot.value['payment_method'].toString();

        RideDetails rideDetails = RideDetails();
        rideDetails.ride_request_id = rideRequestId;
        rideDetails.pickup_address = pickUpAddress;
        rideDetails.dropOff_address = dropOffAddress;
        rideDetails.pickup = LatLng(pickUpLocationLat, pickUpLocationLng);
        rideDetails.dropOff = LatLng(dropOffLocationLat, dropOffLocationLng);
        rideDetails.payment_method = paymentMethod;

        print("Information :: ");
        print(rideDetails.pickup_address);
        print(rideDetails.dropOff_address);

        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => NotificationDialog(rideDetails: rideDetails,),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

The code above is part of my pushNotificationService.dart file,

and this is a block of code from my notificationDialog.dart file

```
 Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [

                  FlatButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    textColor: Colors.red,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    onPressed: ()
                    {
                      assetsAudioPlayer.stop();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Cancel".toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(width: 20.0),

                  RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                    onPressed: ()
                    {
                      assetsAudioPlayer.stop();
                    },
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text("Accept".toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

I also added provided the dependency in the pubspec.yaml file

```
assets_audio_player: ^2.0.13+1
```

Not sure what may be causing the error but I hoping for some assistance. Thank you in advance.